# MATLAB: create new matrix from existing matrix according to specifications

Tags: matlab, matrix

Assume we have the following data:

```
H_T = [36 66 21 65 52 67 73; 31 23 19 33 36 39 42]
P   = [40 38 39 40 35 32 37]
```

Using MATLAB 7.0, I want to create three new matrices that have the following properties:

The matrix `H` (the first part in matrix `H_T`) will be divided to 3 intervals:

- Matrix 1: the 1st interval contains the `H` values between 20 to 40
- Matrix 2: the 2nd interval contains the `H` values between 40 to 60
- Matrix 3: the 3rd interval contains the `H` values between 60 to 80

The important thing is that the corresponding `T` and `P` will also be included in their new matrices meaning that `H` will control the new matrices depending on the specifications defined above.

So, the resultant matrices will be:

```
H_T_1 = [36 21; 31 19]
P_1   = [40 39]

H_T_2 = [52; 36]
P_2   = [35]

H_T_3 = [66 65 67 73; 23 33 39 42]
P_3   = [38 40 32 37]
```

Actually, this is a simple example and it is easy by looking to create the new matrices depending on the specifications, BUT in my values I have thousands of numbers which makes it very difficult to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick solution

```
[~,bins] = histc(H_T(1,:), [20 40 60 80]);

outHT = cell(3,1);
outP = cell(3,1);

for i=1:3
    idx = (bins == i);
    outHT{i} = H_T(:,idx);
    outP{i} = P(idx);
end
```

then you access the matrices as:

```
>> outHT{3}
ans =
    66    65    67    73
    23    33    39    42
>> outP{3}
ans =
    38    40    32    37
```

Comment: note that you didn't specify in your question how to deal with values outside those ranges, and whether the ranges boundaries are inclusive/exclusive??

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Unfortunately, it gave me this error:

??? [~,bins] = histc(H_T(1,:), [20 40 60 80]); 
      |
Error: Incomplete or misformed expression or statement.

and when I wrote:

 help bins

it gave me:

bins.m not found.

I am using MATLAB 7.0 and I think the function bins is not defined

in this version.

Actually, the values are not bounded, but I want to know how

to deal with this problem and I have in my real data, the maximum

value of H is 100, and the minimum is 1

thanks

regards

Comment: Oh I forget, just replace the tilde `~` with a dummy variable. On the other point, it depends what you want to do with values outside the ranges; the solution above just ignores those, but you can easily recover them by finding the elements with `bins==0`

Comment: thanks alot for this help.

My problem is solved..

thanks.

best regards